# Node to String - Java - Large files

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I would like to change a function that I have in Java to work with large files. I have read about `SAX`, `StAX` but I cannot understand how they work and which solution is the best.

The function I am currently using is the following one:

```
public static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    Source source = new DOMSource(node);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Edit: the input parameter cannot be changed (`Node node`) and the return parameter has to be a String.
I want a function that does the same but using SAX, Stax, ... in order to work with large files.

Edit2:

The structure of the "node" (org.w3c.dom.Node) that I receive in the function is:

```
<test>
<test1>
    <test2>JVBERi0xLjQKJcOk (This is a base 64 file. The size of this file can be 5MB, 20MB, 400MB. The maximum size is 400MB</test2>
    <test3>PDF</test3>
</test1>
<test4>
    <test5>Test description</test5>
</test4>
```

As you can see the "test2" node holds a file in Base 64. This node can hold a file of 5MB, 20MB, 100MB, ... up to 400MB.

The OOM exception is thrown is the following line:

```
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Hi there. Please, consider adding the exact question. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Just edited the question adding what I wan to achieve. Thanks Sergey.

Comment: Are you asking about parsing XML or writing out XML? SAX API is useful if you are parsing XML - but you've already got `Node node` in memory and your code is converting back to XML. Use a FileWriter in place of StringWriter to avoid adding memory footprint of the XML to your process.

Comment: @DuncG I have to do what the function does. It takes a node and return a string. The OOM is happening in the "transformer.transorm(source, result)". If I use a FileWriter, will I have to save the file on disk and then read it? Many thanks

Comment: OOM isn't mentioned in the question! Add details on size of the XML that fails and try pre-sizing the `StringWriter(estimatedSize)`. You ought to make the receiver read from a stream not String.

Comment: Hi @DuncG Just added more information after the "Edit2". Many thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Any code that relies on instantiating 400MB string from another 400MB data structure in memory is brittle - and my advice is don't do it.  Instead redesign your APIs so that `String` is not the intermediate data format and 400MB of data is not instantiated. Consider one of these:

1. make the caller pass the `OutputStream` or `Writer` - this means that they can send the XML directly to the destination of their choice.
2. Save to File or database for them to retrieve.
3. Save to File, and read from file using `Files.readString(tempfile)`

If you continue with your code you need to change the VM settings `-Xmx` to give your process a LOT more memory. But how much?

BOTH of these lines are making a copy of ~400MB data structure so you'll need at least 800MB larger:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); // Copy of node as XML text
return sw.toString();                 // Copy of sw as XML text
```

However consider this test program demonstrating memory used by `StringWriter()` when appending characters:

```
private static void test(int size, StringWriter sw) {
    TreeSet<Integer> sizes = new TreeSet<>();
    int capacity = sw.getBuffer().capacity();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sw.append('X');
        sizes.add(sw.getBuffer().capacity());
    }
    System.out.println("StringWriter("+capacity+") => sizes: "+sizes);
}
```

Calling with:

```
test(typicalSize, new StringWriter());
test(typicalSize, new StringWriter(typicalSize));
```

Prints:

```
StringWriter(16) => sizes: [16, 34, 70, 142, 286, 574, 1150, 2302, 4606, 9214, 18430, 36862, 73726, 147454, 294910, 589822, 1179646, 2359294, 4718590, 9437182, 18874366, 37748734, 75497470, 150994942, 301989886, 603979774]
StringWriter(419430400) => sizes: [419430400]
```

This shows that if you don't pre-size StringWriter the internal buffer is re-allocated many times to 300MB then 600MB just before the 400MB copy made by `sw.toString()`. Thus > 1.4GB may be needed, and if the garbage collector isn't keeping up your allocations don't be surprised to find that much more than 2GB extra memory is required to stop your OOM.

**NOTE** all of the above estimates assume compact strings. If you are using older JDK or you have multi-byte charsets in the XML then the memory usage is in `char` not `byte`.